# Microsoft Flow how to get the Azure Devops Connector to return multiple pages when querying users

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, powerapps, power-automate

When using the Azure DevOps Connector in Microsoft flow to query the ADO api users. It only returns 500 users. How can I get it to return the rest of the users?

[image]

I need it to pass back in the `continuationToken` and return the next page of results.

Comment: It seems your issue is more related to Microsoft flow rather than DevOps. You may check `For each` action to see whether it can achieve what you want.

Comment: I do say this is an Flow issue. I am using the Azure DevOps "Connector" in Flow.